# Cannot add/update packages in Xamarin Studio, updated to alpha Xamarin 6.1

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am working with Xamarin.Forms using Xamarin Studio. I update to Xamarin 6.0.1 Build 9 and I couldn't add packages. So I switched to Alpha Xamarin 6.1 to add packages, last week it worked, but for 2 days ago not working at all. I want to add SQLite.Net Extension-PCL. I don't know what I doing wrong. Someone have the same issue?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please share as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are seeing is:

```
The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between the year 0 and 10,000.
```

This is due to a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40916) in Mono which affects NuGet 3.

Workarounds are:

1. Use Xamarin Studio 6.0. This uses NuGet 2 which is not affected by this bug.
2. Switch your timezone on the local machine to be a zero or positive offset with respect to UTC. For example, using UTC+0 as your timezone will allow you to install NuGet packages on your machine, after Xamarin Studio is restarted.
3. Wait for a release of Mono with this fix. I believe there is a version of Mono that fixes this problem available on the beta channel.